# Looking for a closed form solution to an infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics

I have a model with a likelihood function which approximates the following sum:

$
T(n,\mu,\lambda) = \sum\limits_{p=0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^{n+p}\mu^p}{(n+p)!}
$

Where $\lambda>0$, $n$ is a positive integer and $0<\mu<1$.

Within my model, I'm currently truncating $p$ based on some simple rules. I'd obviously prefer a nice analytical solution for $T$ to speed things up, but am not particularly sure at how to proceed in finding a solution (non-mathematician).

1) Is there a simple solution to this infinite sum?

2) Does anyone have any recommendations on what to do/think about when faced with these kinds of sums? Is there a set of paths that are sensible to try?

3) Or, if there are no solution, how would you choose the point at which to truncate $p$?

Thanks

Comment: CAS says :$\frac{e^{\lambda  \mu } \lambda ^n (\lambda  \mu )^{-n} (\Gamma (n)-\Gamma (n,\lambda  \mu ))}{\Gamma (n)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, notice that:
$$T(n,\mu,\lambda) = \lambda^n\sum\limits_{p=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\lambda\mu)^{p}}{(n+p)!}$$

Moreover, recall that:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!} = e^x.$$

Perform a change of variable:

$$p = h - n \Rightarrow h = n+p \\
p = 0 \Rightarrow h = n\\p = \infty \Rightarrow h = \infty.$$

Therefore:

$$T(n,\mu,\lambda) = \lambda^n\sum\limits_{h=n}^{\infty}\frac{(\lambda\mu)^{h-n}}{h!} = \lambda^n(\lambda\mu)^{-n} \sum\limits_{h=n}^{\infty}\frac{(\lambda\mu)^{h}}{h!} =\\
= \mu^{-n}\left(\sum\limits_{h=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\lambda\mu)^{h}}{h!} - \sum\limits_{h=0}^{n-1}\frac{(\lambda\mu)^{h}}{h!}\right) = \\
= \mu^{-n}\left(e^{\lambda\mu} - \sum\limits_{h=0}^{n-1}\frac{(\lambda\mu)^{h}}{h!}\right).$$

The term $\sum\limits_{h=0}^{n-1}\frac{(\lambda\mu)^{h}}{h!}$ can be easily evaluated in a numerical way since it is the sum of finite elements.

Comment: Great, thanks! I was trying to shoehorn the exponential in but didn't think of doing a change of variables. Nice approach, helps a lot!

Comment: @oioioi you are welcome